# How to get css background color on <tr> tag to span entire row

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have tried everything I can think of in css in order to get a background color to span an entire table row (<tr> tag) But I keep getting a white border around each  cell.

CSS (excerpt):

```
/*alternating row*/
table, tr, td, th {margin:0;border:0;padding:0;}
tr.rowhighlight {background-color:#f0f8ff;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;}
```

HTML (excerpt):

```
<tr class="rowhighlight"><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
```

It just does not want to cooperate. Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
```

Comment: table border-collapse doesn't do it Firefox 4

Comment: Works fine for me in FF4. Try using Reset CSS. There must be something overriding. Or let us see your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: add `<table id="standings" style="border-collapse:collapse">` Worked for me in Firebug on your site.

Comment: Wow, that's so weird. It works inline but not through the css. The styles in the css are the last set defined. Well, at least it works. Thanks Jaspero.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to use `border-spacing` as it allows more flexibility. For instance, you could do

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
}
```

Which would only collapse the vertical borders and leave the horizontal ones in tact, which is what it sounds like the OP was actually looking for.

Note that `border-spacing: 0` is not the same as `border-collapse: collapse`. You will need to use the latter if you want to add your own border to a `tr` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
    .rowhighlight > td { background: green;}
```

Answer (score 5):

Removing the borders *should* make the background color paint without any gaps between the cells. If you look carefully at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/NfjhT), you should see that the light blue color stretches across the row with no white gaps.

If all else fails, try this:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

Comment: table border-collapse did not do it either

Comment: looks fine in jsFiddle -- just doesn't look right in Firefox 4

Comment: Looks fine for me in Firefox 4. Maybe you've got an inheritance/specificity problem, or a doctype issue (unlikely).

Comment: I'm using FF4 and the jsFiddle example has no gaps. Perhaps you have some other code interfering with it? I suggest downloading Firebug and seeing what rules are actually being used.

Comment: I do use firebug. my css is the last set of css

Comment: js fiddle has it's own style sheet that applies `table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }` which makes it never show the gaps (even if you remove all the css formatting except the row colour

Answer (score 3):

```
tr.rowhighlight td, tr.rowhighlight th{
    background-color:#f0f8ff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and Chrome are different
Chrome ignores the TR's background-color
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/T4NK3R/9SE4p/

```
<tr style="background-color:#F00">
     <td style="background-color:#FFF; border-radius:20px">
</tr>
```

In FF the TD gets red corners, in Chrome not

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the spacing to zero?

```
/*alternating row*/
table, tr, td, th {margin:0;border:0;padding:0;spacing:0;}
tr.rowhighlight {background-color:#f0f8ff;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;spacing:0;}
```

Comment: Did you mean `border-spacing`?

Comment: Spacing is not a valid css style, but border-spacing is. I tried border-spacing and that did not do it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, even within a div:

```
      div.cntrblk tr:hover td {
        line-height: 150%;
        background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 150%;
        border: 0;
      }
```

It selected the entire row, but I'd like it to not do the header, haven't looked at that yet.  It also ***partially*** fixed the fonts that wouldn't scale-up with the hover??? Apparently you to have apply settings to the cell not the row, but select all the component cells with the tr:hover.  On to tracking down the in-consistent font scaling problem.  Sweet that CSS will do this.