# HTML tr background color without collapsing borders

Tags: html, css

I want to put a background color on a whole `<tr>`. I tries it, and got white gaps between cells. I found many answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680753/how-to-get-css-background-color-on-tr-tag-to-span-entire-row) suggesting collapsing the table's borders. However, I don't want the borders collapsed! I want the borders on all other rows, just no on this one colored row (or more accurately, I want the spacing of the borders even in this row, but the BG color should include the spacing)

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qEg9L/1/ . As you can see, the rest of the table's cells are various colors, and the border helps to distinguish them. Only the top row is a solid color, and I don't want the borders

Comment: how about setting the background on all the td's of that tr

Comment: what have u tried and where is your fiddle

Comment: how about setting border colors of the TD's in that row?

Comment: @caramba I added the fiddle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `border-collapse: collapse;` but then add your own border

**EDIT** (now that you posted your fiddle)

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qEg9L/5/)**

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
table td{
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
```

---

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/uzxWp/170/)**

```
<table>
  <tr class="withBack">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>


  table{
    border-collapse: collapse;

  }
  table td{
    border: 5px solid green;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
.withBack
{
    background: pink;
}
.withBack td
{
    background: pink;
    border: 5px solid pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a css file to color only td tags, then youll be able to see borders.

Answer (score 0):

just add this style to table like this

```
<table style='border-spacing:0px'>
    // your code.
</table>
```