# CSS3 :nth-child(odd) Selector neither selecting columns nor rows

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table using tr:nth-child(odd) to alternate background for rows in a table.

HTML

```css
/*-----------#602 SAO Styles-----------------------------*/

/*---------SAO Global------------*/

.sao-pricing-table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.sao-pricing-table table td {
  height: 20px;
}
table.sao-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/*-----Basic Title Cells---------*/

.sao-top-1 {
  border: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40%;
}
.sao-top-2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px solid #a8b5b9;
  background-color: #003869;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30%;
}
.sao-top-2-title {
  font-size: 110%;
}
.sao-top-2-type {
  font-size: 120%;
}
.sao-top-2-price {
  font-size: 100%;
}
/*------Gold Title Cells------*/

.sao-top-3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0px solid #a8b5b9;
  background-color: #F2A405;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: ;
  width: 30%;
}
.sao-top-3-title {
  font-size: 110%;
}
.sao-top-3-type {
  font-size: 130%;
}
.sao-top-3-price {
  font-size: 100%;
}
/*----Regular Cells-----*/

#sao-table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 20%;
}
tr.sao-zebra:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #23282D !important;
}
.sao-feature {
  text-align: left !important;
}
/* Checkmark Style-----*/

.sao-checkmark {
  font-size: 125%;
  color: #F2A405;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="sao-pricing-table">
  <table class="sao-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sao-top-1">
        </th>
        <th class="sao-top-2">
          <span class="sao-top-2-title">Some Text</span>
          <span class="sao-top-2-type">More Text</span>
          <span class="sao-top-2-price">Even More Text</span>
        </th>
        <th class="sao-top-3">
          <span class="sao-top-3-title">Some Text</span>
          <span class="sao-top-3-type">More Text</span>
          <span class="sao-top-3-price">Even More Text</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="sao-feature">Text</th>
        <td class="sao-detail">Text</td>
        <td class="sao-detail">Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="sao-feature">Text</th>
        <td class="sao-detail">Text</td>
        <td class="sao-detail">Text</td>
      </tr>
```

as is stands, the table has 3 columns. The nth-child pseudo selector is causing every other column to be black, not every other row. What have I done wrong? Edit: the example for row span that was suggested doesn't include the nth-child selector so I'm failing to see how its the same. Can someone fill me in?

Comment: that's a typo, you  have a space just before `:nth-child`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get css background color on <tr> tag to span entire row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680753/how-to-get-css-background-color-on-tr-tag-to-span-entire-row)

Comment: @dippas You could actually close it as a dupe, I voted for that and consider delete my answer ... made it a wiki for now

Comment: The updated code's `tr` does not have a class set to`sao-zebra`, should be like this `<tr class="sao-zebra">`

Comment: Thanks! ok working now. We'll see what happens when i add it to the wp themes custom css...

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in your selector where there shouldn't be one, just before `:nth-child`

```
tr.sao-zebra:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #23282D;
}
```

Comment: changed it and now no styles from this selector are being applied.

Comment: @gthadi works as expected. This is the correct answer, see https://jsfiddle.net/sqma3qL1/ Please double-check your code.